# Data is not displaying while data is been received from api on toggle button call

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to display data showed in the console on my interface shown below. The API call is made when the toggle button is clicked, but that data is not being loaded into the UI.

[image]

This is what my typescript code looks like:

```js
getCardById(cardId) {
  this._transactionService.getCardById(cardId).subscribe((response) => {
    if (!this._commonService.isEmptyObject(response)) {
      var cardById = new CardDecrypt();
      cardById.other = new Other();
      cardById.maskedCardNumber = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.maskedCardNumber);
      cardById.expirationMonth = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.expirationMonth);
      cardById.expirationYear = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.expirationYear);
      cardById.fourDigit = cardById.maskedCardNumber.slice(cardById.maskedCardNumber.length - 4);
      cardById.default = response?.default;
      cardById.id = response?.id;
      cardById.name = response?.name;
      cardById.type = response?.type;
      cardById.other.address1 = (response.other.address1 != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.address1) : '';
      cardById.other.address2 = (response.other.address2 != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.address2) : '';
      cardById.other.city = (response.other.city != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.city) : '';
      cardById.other.country = (response.other.country != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.country) : '';
      cardById.other.nameOnCard = (response.other.nameOnCard != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.nameOnCard) : '';
      cardById.other.number = (response.other.number != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.number) : '';
      cardById.other.state = (response.other.state != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.state) : '';
      cardById.other.zipcode = (response.other.zipcode != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.zipcode) : '';
      console.log(cardById);
    }
    else {

    }
  });
}
```

This is how I am storing the information and displaying it on the UI:

```html
<div class="payment-history-right ml-auto">
  <a class="trigger-dropdown" href="#{{card?.id}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{card?.id}}" (click)="getCardById(card?.id)">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down "></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="{{card?.id}}" class="payment-history-item-detail collapse">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="ph-item-detail-title">Name on card</div>
      <div class="ph-item-detail-desc">{{cardById?.name}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="ph-item-detail-title">Billing Address</div>
      <div class="ph-item-detail-subtitle">{{cardById?.other.nameOnCard}}</div>
      <div class="ph-item-detail-desc">
        {{cardById?.other.address1}} <br />
        {{cardById?.other.address2}}, <br />
        {{cardById?.other.city}}, <br />
        {{cardById?.other.state}}-{{cardById?.other.zipcode}} <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the values are not displaying.

Comment: Can you attach your code to the question or create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)? It is not recommended to post the code as images as mentioned in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: Are `card` and `cardById` properties of your component?

Answer (score 1):

The reason: `view` is displayed before the data is being loaded from the API. So, you can add the `*ngIf` directive to wait for it. Also, if you have used `OnPush` strategy, you might need to use manual change detection. Toogle  `showData` as per the usage.

```
<div *ngIf="showData" class="payment-history-right ml-auto">
      <a class="trigger-dropdown" href="#{{card?.id}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{card?.id}}" (click)="getCardById(card?.id)">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down "></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="{{card?.id}}" class="payment-history-item-detail collapse">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="ph-item-detail-title">Name on card</div>
        <div class="ph-item-detail-desc">{{cardById?.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="ph-item-detail-title">Billing Address</div>
        <div class="ph-item-detail-subtitle">{{cardById?.other.nameOnCard}}</div>
        <div class="ph-item-detail-desc">
          {{cardById?.other.address1}} <br />
          {{cardById?.other.address2}}, <br />
          {{cardById?.other.city}}, <br />
          {{cardById?.other.state}}-{{cardById?.other.zipcode}} <br />
        </div>
      </div>
```

In your component file:

```
public showData: boolean = false;
public cardById: any

 getCardById(cardId) {
this._transactionService.getCardById(cardId).subscribe((response) => {
  if (!this._commonService.isEmptyObject(response)) {
    this.cardById = new CardDecrypt();
    cardById.other = new Other();
    cardById.maskedCardNumber = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.maskedCardNumber);
    cardById.expirationMonth = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.expirationMonth);
    cardById.expirationYear = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.expirationYear);
    cardById.fourDigit = cardById.maskedCardNumber.slice(cardById.maskedCardNumber.length - 4);
    cardById.default = response?.default;
    cardById.id = response?.id;
    cardById.name = response?.name;
    cardById.type = response?.type;
    cardById.other.address1 = (response.other.address1 != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.address1) : '';
    cardById.other.address2 = (response.other.address2 != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.address2) : '';
    cardById.other.city = (response.other.city != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.city) : '';
    cardById.other.country = (response.other.country != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.country) : '';
    cardById.other.nameOnCard = (response.other.nameOnCard != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.nameOnCard) : '';
    cardById.other.number = (response.other.number != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.number) : '';
    cardById.other.state = (response.other.state != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.state) : '';
    cardById.other.zipcode = (response.other.zipcode != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.zipcode) : '';
    console.log(cardById);
    this.showData = true; // it will update the view 
  }
  else {

  }
});
```

Comment: thankyou so much for help but the issue was i was using cardbyid as local variable after declaring it public and using it with this.cardbyid issue got resolved. Thanks Apoorva